# Simplifying code using arrays in Swift (core location)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mapkit, core-location

I am doing little project: If person is near given coordinates it outputs "Hello". It is working but I think it is too much code if I keep making so many variables. Is there a way to organize it or make it easier to add coordinates. I tried using array but can't get it to work. What could be the best solution? I am pretty much new to Swift syntax. Any help is much appreciated.

```
let addressLocation:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 37.334421, longitude: -122.037987)
let addressLocation2:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 37.334395, longitude: -122.041173)


let meters:CLLocationDistance = location!.distanceFromLocation(addressLocation)
let meters2:CLLocationDistance = location!.distanceFromLocation(addressLocation2)


if (meters <= 50.00000000 || meters2 <= 50.0000000){
    print("Hello")
}else{
    print("No")
}
```

Comment: Those are not "many variables". Or can this grow to more than two locations? Then an array may indeed be a good idea.

Comment: Swift can infer all these types, so no need to spell out `:CLLocationDistance` and such.

Comment: You could also save the locations in a plist file as an array and then pull them out from there. It would probably be a good idea to put your `if` in its own function that you call passing in the two required variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If needed, you can get an array of all close locations with `locations.filter({ location!.distanceFromLocation($0) < maxDistance })`, however, for your purpose, this is the simplest way I could think of:

```
var locations = [CLLocation(latitude: 37.334421, longitude: -122.037987),
                 CLLocation(latitude: 37.334395, longitude: -122.041173)]
let maxDistance = 50.0

if locations.contains({ location!.distanceFromLocation($0) < maxDistance }) {
    print("Hello")
} else {
    print("No close locations")
}
```

Comment: `isEmpty` instead of `count > 0`? In the end you are just reimplementing `contains`

Comment: @Sulthan you are right, contains makes it simpler, updated

Answer (score 2):

This is how you would use an array to hold the locations.

```
var location = CLLocation(latitude: 37.334421, longitude: -122.037987)
var locations:[CLLocation] = [CLLocation(latitude: 37.334421, longitude: -122.037987),
                              CLLocation(latitude: 37.334395, longitude: -122.041173)]
var distances = locations.map{location.distanceFromLocation($0)}
let maxDistance = 50.0
if (distances.contains{$0 < maxDistance}) {
    print("Hello")
} else {
    print("No")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you implement a function that receives a given location, a list of addresses and perform your check.

```
func check(location:CLLocation?, addresses:[CLLocation]) {
    guard let location = location else { return }
    if (addresses.contains { $0.distanceFromLocation(location) < 50 }) {
        print("Hello")
    } else {
        print("No")
    }
}
```